# Where can I see all the learned/ignored spelling in Pages 5.5?

Tags: mac, pages, spellcheck, spelling

I've added some words that are not in the standard Apple dictionary in Pages 5.5 via the 'learn'/'ignore spelling' function.

Is there any way where I can see a comprehensive list of the words that I have added to the 'learn'/'ignore' list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your custom words spelling are stored in this plain-text file:

```
~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary
```

---

You can **view it from your terminal** using:

```
cat ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary
```

---

Or **open in a text editor of your choice** by using its `Open` menu item then:

- Press `Cmd+Shift+G` to open the `Go to folder` dialogue
- Paste `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` into the box
- Press enter

Comment: This is great - do you know how to also "un-ignore" spelling for words? There doesn't seem to be a similar text file for this feature.